# How can I measure the coverage (in production system)?

Tags: python, code-coverage, performance-testing

I would like to measure the coverage of my Python code which gets executed in the production system.

I want an answer to this question:

> Which lines get executed often (hot spots) and which lines are never used (dead code)?

Of course this must not slow down my production site.

I am **not** talking about measuring the coverage of tests.

Comment: For what kind of code you want to this? Django web server something else? Also I hope you understand that doing something like this in production is never recommended

Comment: I'm also rather unclear on what exactly is meant by "code which gets executed in the production system" - but you can move that exact code to a private repo and configure continuous integration for coverage.

Answer (score 9):

I assume you are not talking about test suite code coverage which the other answer is referring to. That is a job for CI indeed.

If you want to know which code paths are hit often in your production system, then you're going to have to do some instrumentation / profiling. This will have a cost. You cannot add measurements for free. You can do it cheaply though and typically you would only run it for short amounts of time, long enough until you have your data.

Python has [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to do full profiling, measuring call counts per function etc. This will give you the most accurate data but will likely have relatively high impact on performance.

Alternatively, you can do statistical profiling which basically means you sample the stack on a timer instead of instrumenting everything. This can be much cheaper, even with high sampling rate! The downside of course is a loss of precision.

Even though it is surprisingly easy to do in Python, this stuff is still a bit much to put into an answer here. There is an excellent [blog post by the Nylas team](https://www.nylas.com/blog/performance/) on this exact topic though.

The sampler below was lifted from the Nylas blog with some tweaks. After you start it, it fires an interrupt every millisecond and records the current call stack:

```
import collections
import signal

class Sampler(object):
    def __init__(self, interval=0.001):
        self.stack_counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
        self.interval = interval

    def start(self): 
        signal.signal(signal.VTALRM, self._sample)
        signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_VIRTUAL, self.interval, 0)

    def _sample(self, signum, frame):
        stack = []
        while frame is not None:
            formatted_frame = '{}({})'.format(
                frame.f_code.co_name,
                frame.f_globals.get('__name__'))
            stack.append(formatted_frame)
            frame = frame.f_back
        formatted_stack = ';'.join(reversed(stack))
        self.stack_counts[formatted_stack] += 1
        signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_VIRTUAL, self.interval, 0)
```

You inspect `stack_counts` to see what your program has been up to. This data can be plotted in a [flame-graph](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html) which makes it really obvious to see in which code paths your program is spending the most time.

Comment: So "production system" coverage is coverage of code DEPLOYED in production? e.g. compiled into executable and seeing how often code executes while used by user -- then indeed, my answer's irrelevant

Comment: We kind of have to guess from the question right, so who knows. I think this is what he meant, yeah :-)

Comment: +1 for "This will have a cost. You cannot add measurements for free." Any form of measurement will introduce some overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it right you want to learn which parts of your application is used most often by users.

---

**TL;DR;**

Use one of the metrics frameworks for python if you do not want to do it by hand. Some of them are above:

- [DataDog](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/python/)
- [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/)

  - [Prometheus Python Client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python)
- [Splunk](https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/python/sdk-python/)

---

It is usually done by function level and it actually depends on application;

- If it is a desktop app with internet access:

  You can create a simple db and collect how many times your functions are called. For accomplish it you can write a simple function and call it inside every function that you want to track. After that you can define an asynchronous task to upload your data to internet.
- If it is a web application:

  You can track which functions are called from js (mostly preferred for user behaviour tracking) or from web api. It is a good practice to start from outer to go inner. First detect which end points are frequently called (If you are using a proxy like nginx you can analyze server logs to gather information. It is the easiest and cleanest way). After that insert a logger to every other function that you want to track and simply analyze your logs for every week or month.

But you want to analyze your production code line by line (it is a very bad idea) you can start your application with python profilers. Python has one already: [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe make a text file and through your every program method just append some text referenced to it like "Method one executed". Run the web application like 10 times thoroughly  as a viewer would and after this make a python program that reads the file and counts a specific parts of it or maybe even a pattern and adds it to a variable and outputs the variables.